# Customize Content (Add Footer And Header Note) In SwiftUI WebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, swiftui

I'm so new at Swift and SwiftUI. I want to display webview via WebKit:WKWebView.

I try to implement it like below:

```
var webView: WKWebView? {
    didSet {
        guard let webView = webView else { return }
        webView.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }
}
```

You can find more details from here: https://github.com/sbertix/Swiftagram/issues/48

When I implement it, it looks like below:

[image]

But I want to customize content of WebView like below:

[image]

Is there a way to implement it like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simple is just wrap those three views (header-webview-footer) in `VStack`, ie like below (of course your header footer can be any)

Note: `WebView` any your WKWebView wrapper (I took for testing from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61059318/12299030)

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HeaderView()
            WebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com"))
            FooterView()
        }
}

struct HeaderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Header Note")
            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 60)
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}

struct FooterView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Footer Note")
            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: Asperi, thanks for your answer. When you look my example, webview doesn't cover/spread to whole page. Is there an implementation about it like LayoutConstraint?

Comment: No, screen shot shows sheet, just put DemoView (your view of course) in sheet where needed.

Comment: Source code is: https://github.com/sbertix/Swiftagram/tree/main/Examples/Followers   Webview Caller: https://github.com/sbertix/Swiftagram/blob/main/Examples/Followers/Followers/Login/LoginView.swift