# Reload web view contents when SwiftUI button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

## Aim

- To display a web view inside a SwiftUI view
- Reload the contents of the web view when a button (SwiftUI) is pressed.

## My Attempt

- I have made an attempt to do the above.
- Pass a Publisher (`CurrentValueSubject`) to the `UIViewRepresentable`
- Observe for any new values from the publisher
- If the value is `true` refresh the web view

## Question:

- Is there a better way to do this? or is my approach reasonable?

## Code:

### WebView

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import Combine

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    let shouldRefresh: CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        context.coordinator.navigation = webView.load(request)
        context.coordinator.webView = webView
        context.coordinator.observeChanges(for: shouldRefresh)
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        print("update view called")
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
}

extension WebView {
    
    class Coordinator {
        var navigation: WKNavigation?
        var webView: WKWebView?
        private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
        
        @MainActor
        func observeChanges(for shouldRefresh: CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>) {
            cancellable = shouldRefresh
                .filter { $0 == true }
                .sink { [weak self] newValue in
                    self?.navigation = self?.webView?.reload()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

### ContentView

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Reload") {
                print("reload pressed")
                reload()
            }
            WebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!,
                    shouldRefresh: model.shouldRefresh)
        }
    }
    
    func reload() {
        model.shouldRefresh.send(true)
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    class Model: ObservableObject {
        var shouldRefresh = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61059318/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi your solution works perfectly, but I can't understand how. My understanding is `shouldRefresh = true` will cause the state to change and the view to be recreated, but why isn't `makeUIView` not called? instead only `updateUIView` called

Comment: This is how by-design representable reacts on changes of dependent bindings.

Comment: Cool thanks a lot!! My initial approach was changing the environment value, it caused makUIView to be called again. Binding is much nicer and works as expected